# what is an image resource identifier?

Tags: php

I am reading the php [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) for the function `imagecreatetruecolor`, which returns an image resource identifier on success. What does it mean by "image resource identifier"? I searched the PHP documentation for this term but did not find it in the first two pages of documentation.

Comment: See the example in the manual - it's the image resource you created. Every GD function you call subsequently needs that image identifier to know which image it should be working on.

Comment: A variable that you can then use to identify the particular image with, as far as php is concerned. A rough equivalent would be an HBITMAP in windows land.

Comment: It is probably just an object which represents the image for use with other image querying and manipulating methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's basically just a special type of object for use with the `gdlib` - other functions will require this resource as a parameter such as [`imagecolorallocate`](https://www.php.net/imagecolorallocate).

It stores the information about the image you're creating for further modification with other functions later on.

A little bit of info on resources from php.net [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)

Answer (score 1):

**image resource identifier** is a structure (in **C** terms) defined to hold  the information about the image. Here is its definition in PHP sources code:

```
typedef struct gdImageStruct {
    /* Palette-based image pixels */
    unsigned char ** pixels;
    int sx;
    int sy;
    /* These are valid in palette images only. See also
        'alpha', which appears later in the structure to
        preserve binary backwards compatibility */
    int colorsTotal;
    int red[gdMaxColors];
    int green[gdMaxColors];
    int blue[gdMaxColors];
    int open[gdMaxColors];
    /* For backwards compatibility, this is set to the
        first palette entry with 100% transparency,
        and is also set and reset by the
        gdImageColorTransparent function. Newer
        applications can allocate palette entries
        with any desired level of transparency; however,
        bear in mind that many viewers, notably
        many web browsers, fail to implement
        full alpha channel for PNG and provide
        support for full opacity or transparency only. */
    int transparent;
    int *polyInts;
    int polyAllocated;
    struct gdImageStruct *brush;
    struct gdImageStruct *tile;
    int brushColorMap[gdMaxColors];
    int tileColorMap[gdMaxColors];
    int styleLength;
    int stylePos;
    int *style;
    int interlace;
    /* New in 2.0: thickness of line. Initialized to 1. */
    int thick;
    /* New in 2.0: alpha channel for palettes. Note that only
        Macintosh Internet Explorer and (possibly) Netscape 6
        really support multiple levels of transparency in
        palettes, to my knowledge, as of 2/15/01. Most
        common browsers will display 100% opaque and
        100% transparent correctly, and do something
        unpredictable and/or undesirable for levels
        in between. TBB */
    int alpha[gdMaxColors];
    /* Truecolor flag and pixels. New 2.0 fields appear here at the
        end to minimize breakage of existing object code. */
    int trueColor;
    int ** tpixels;
    /* Should alpha channel be copied, or applied, each time a
        pixel is drawn? This applies to truecolor images only.
        No attempt is made to alpha-blend in palette images,
        even if semitransparent palette entries exist.
        To do that, build your image as a truecolor image,
        then quantize down to 8 bits. */
    int alphaBlendingFlag;
    /* Should antialias functions be used */
    int antialias;
    /* Should the alpha channel of the image be saved? This affects
        PNG at the moment; other future formats may also
        have that capability. JPEG doesn't. */
    int saveAlphaFlag;


    /* 2.0.12: anti-aliased globals */
    int AA;
    int AA_color;
    int AA_dont_blend;
    unsigned char **AA_opacity;
    int AA_polygon;
    /* Stored and pre-computed variables for determining the perpendicular
     * distance from a point to the anti-aliased line being drawn:
     */
    int AAL_x1;
    int AAL_y1;
    int AAL_x2;
    int AAL_y2;
    int AAL_Bx_Ax;
    int AAL_By_Ay;
    int AAL_LAB_2;
    float AAL_LAB;

    /* 2.0.12: simple clipping rectangle. These values must be checked for safety when set; please use gdImageSetClip */
    int cx1;
    int cy1;
    int cx2;
    int cy2;
    gdInterpolationMethod interpolation_id;
    interpolation_method interpolation;
} gdImage;
```